# onMouseOver- DIV background image change but with restriction: No JavaScript "tag", no Style CSS?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

```
<div id="test" name="myDIV" style="background-image: url('img/img3'); width: 280px;    height: 150px " >

</div>
<br><br>
<hr>
<img alt="" id="1" src="img/image1.jpg"  onmouseover="javascript:    document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage=url('img/img1')">
<img alt="" id="2" src="img/image2.jpg"  onmouseover="javascript: document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage=url('img/img2)">
```

Something like that, no outside clear `<javascript> function changeBgImage() </javascript>`
is allowed. No outside CSS is allowed. I know this company is very retro ~ ^^

Any help? currently, this shows the error.

Answer (score 2):

url() is not a JavaScript function. It's actually part of the CSS value you want to set, so you'll probably have to do some evil double quoting, like this:

```
/* ... */ .style.backgroundImage = 'url(\'img/img1\')';
```

PS. you're also missing a single quote at the end of the first `onmouseover` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img alt="" id="1" src="img/image1" onmouseover="javascript: document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(\'img/img1\')';">
<img alt="" id="2" src="img/image2" onmouseover="javascript: document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage='url(\'img/img2\')';">
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that will break the HTML attributes because HTML doesn't care about the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('test').style.backgroundImage = "url('img/img2)'"
```

Use that instead of your current inline JavaScript, and it should work. If you think about how the CSS would look:

```
#test { background-image: url('img/img3'); }
```

Then it's clear that `url` is part of the value of the CSS property, and therefore needs to be quoted.